# What is the following MACRO doing?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, macros, clang

```
#define DEFINE_VECTOR_MEMBER_DATA_S(T,c,n,s)    T c ## :: ## n[s]
```

I have it in the legacy code. It is compiled by MSVC 2022, but not with Clang.
I plan to replace it, but before it I need to know what does it do.

Comment: It looks like it's supposed to be a long-winded way of defining an array. Those `##` operators, at best, don't do anything useful. It's utterly pointless, so, yes, get rid of it. It's just noise.

Comment: At worst, the code technically isn't legal because token pasting must produce a single token. I bet MSVC would reject it as well with `/Zc:preprocessor` (the new PP implementation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It defines a vector which is a static member of a class.

Type `T`.
Class `c`.
Name of vector `n`.
Size of vector `s`.

`##` pastes 2 pieces together, but isn't needed anyway.

If the linker says it the vector's missing just add:

`T c::n[s];`

Into a `.cpp` file with the parts replaced accordingly.